# Getting Rendering Parameter in View

Tags: razor, rendering-parameters

Is there a way to get `Rendering Parameter` in `cshtml` view file without the glass mapper model?

The existing View is already using a model. So want to get the parameter without a model or glass mapper.

The `Rendering parameter` is a `multilist field`, I need the selected value of the field.

Comment: It is a duplicate of https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19534/retrieving-items-from-a-multiselect-rendering-parameter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving items from a multiselect Rendering Parameter](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19534/retrieving-items-from-a-multiselect-rendering-parameter)

Comment: While the answers below prove you _can_ do this. The question should be whether you _should_ do this. If you have a controller action already, just add it to your view model and don't mess up your view with tight coupling to the Sitecore API. If Glass is getting in your way, then ditch Glass...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Parameters`

```
@{
  var rendering = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering;
  string someParameter = rendering.Parameters["my multilist field"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the rendering parameters like this in your view.

```
 string TitleCss = string.Empty, DescriptionCss = string.Empty;

 var rc = Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull;
 if (rc != null)
 {
     var parms = rc.Rendering.Parameters;
     TitleCss = parms["TitleCss"];
     DescriptionCss = parms["DescriptionCss"];
              
     Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField multiselectField = param["your multilist filed"];

     Sitecore.Data.Items.Item[] items = multiselectField.GetItems();

 }
```